# Removing every occurance of \n in a string in C

Tags: c, string, whitespace

I have seen tutorials and tips on this but they are usually not for C. This is what I've written so far:

```
    printf("\nBefore removing: %s", an_name);
    printf("%d", strlen(an_name));

    for (i=0;i<strlen(an_name);i++){
        printf("\nthe loop: %d",i);

        if (an_name[i]!='\n'){
        new_name[i] = an_name[i];
        printf("\nthe loop: %d", i);
    }
    else{//when a \n is detected
        new_name[i] = an_name[i+1];
        i=i+1;
    }   
    printf("\nAfter removing: %s\n", new_name);
    printf("%d", strlen(an_name));
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

> It does half the job. I want to remove the \n character and put all the new characters in a new string. But how?

Comment: Use the function `isspace()` to identify any whitespace character.

Comment: The aim is to delete the \n by carrying all the other characters into a new string. I have no trouble finding the \n character

Comment: The question originally said "or any other whitespace", I was explaining how to find other whitespace.

Comment: yes i realise... I should have left that part out, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need separate indexes for the input array and the output array. Otherwise, you never put anything into the output array in the place where the skipped newline was, so you have an uninitialized value there. In your test, it happened to contain `0`, which is the string terminator, so it just printed everything before that.

You also need to add a null byte at the end of the output string when the loop is done.

You can use `isspace()` to test for any whitespace.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char an_name[20], new_name[20];
    int i;

    strcpy(an_name,"Ant\nho ny");

    printf("\nBefore removing: %s\n", an_name);
    printf("%ld", strlen(an_name));

    int j = 0;
    for (i=0;i<strlen(an_name);i++){
        printf("\nthe loop: %d",i);

        if(!isspace(an_name[i])){
            new_name[j++] = an_name[i];
        }
    }
    new_name[j] = '\0';

    printf("\nAfter removing: %s\n", new_name);
    printf("%ld", strlen(an_name));
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before removing: Ant
ho ny
9
the loop: 0
the loop: 1
the loop: 2
the loop: 3
the loop: 4
the loop: 5
the loop: 6
the loop: 7
the loop: 8
After removing: Anthony
9
```

Comment: @Barmar i modified code as follows `for (i=0;i<strlen(an_name);i++){
        printf("\nthe loop: %d",i);

        if(an_name[i] == '\n'){
           // i++; inc and assign or continue
                continue;
        }        new_name[i] = an_name[i];` here eventhough all character other than new line is assigned to `new_name`, its printing only `Ant`.

Comment: You're still using the same variable `i` for input and output. That's completely wrong.

Comment: @Barmar yes, after Ant there is a null

Answer (score 1):

The new string has to be terminated with null character. You can also use a second variable `j`, and increment `j` when `\n` and space don't appear:

```
int i;
int j = 0;
int len = strlen(an_name);
for(i = 0; i < len; i++) 
{
    printf("\nthe loop: %d", i);
    if(an_name[i] == '\n' || an_name[i] == ' ')
        continue;
    new_name[j++] = an_name[i];
}
new_name[j] = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could take a different approach and only add the character when it's not a space character, you just have to remember to make sure that new string is null terminated.

```
int main(){
    char an_name[20], new_name[20];
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    strcpy(an_name,"Ant\nhony");

    printf("Tacos are delicious!\n");
    printf("\nBefore removing: %s", an_name);
    printf("%d", strlen(an_name));

    for (i=0;i<strlen(an_name);i++){
        printf("\nthe loop: %d",i);

        if(!isspace(an_name[i])){
            j++;
            new_name[j] = an_name[i];
        }

    }
    printf("\nAfter removing: %s\n", new_name);
    printf("%d", strlen(an_name));
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The 2nd call to `printf("%d", strlen(an_name));` probably should have printed the length of the new string, shouldn't it?

Comment: "*not a space character*" the OP is after removing new-lines only, not after removing *all* kind of spaces.